# mcons in dr racket

Tags: lisp, scheme, sicp, racket

I'm having trouble reading output from dr racket. By default it displays lists using mcons. For example, sicp exercise 2.32 produces:

```
> (subsets (list 1 2 3))
(mcons
 (mcons
  '()
  (mcons
   (mcons 3 '())
   (mcons
    (mcons 2 '())
    (mcons
     (mcons 2 (mcons 3 '()))
     (mcons
      (mcons 1 '())
      (mcons
       (mcons 1 (mcons 3 '()))
       (mcons
        (mcons 1 (mcons 2 '()))
        (mcons (mcons 1 (mcons 2 (mcons 3 '()))) '()))))))))
 '())
```

I'm having trouble reading this. Is there a way to make the output look like:

```
 (() (3) (2) (2 3) (1) (1 3) (1 2) (1 2 3))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you know what language are you using in your `#lang` line?  The rest of the instructions below are assuming that you're using a `#lang` line.

---

If you are in `#lang r5rs` and you `display` or `write` the values, you should see the output you expect.

```
> (define p (list 1 2))
> (display p)
(1 2)
> (set-car! p 'one)
> (display p)
(one 2)
```

If you just type the values bare in Interactions, DrRacket will `print` them, and that uses the representation you're seeing.  In DrRacket, you can [customize](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/output-syntax.html) the way that values `print`.  Here's the process, step-by-step:

1. Go to the **Language** menu, and select **Choose Language**.  You should see the language dialog pop up.
2. If the button on the lower left says **Show Details**, click it, and the dialog window should expand to include customizations.
3. Look for the **Output Style** option.  There should be four choices: **Constructor**, **Quasiquote**, **write**, and **print**.  Select **write** style, and then press **Ok** to confirm the customization.

Once you do this, then:

```
> (display (list 1 2))
(1 2)
> (write (list 1 2))
(1 2)
> (list 1 2)
{1 2}
```

It will still print slightly differently than you expect, using curly braces, because it's trying to notate that the list structure is mutable.

If this bothers you, we can fix that.  Add the following line near the top of your program (but after the `#lang` line).

```
(#%require r5rs/init)
```

This line pulls in a Racket-specific module called [`r5rs/init`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/r5rs/r5rs_init-mod.html) that tries to improve r5rs compliance; in particular, the braces should finally print as round ones for mutable pairs.

```
> (display (list 1 2))
(1 2)
> (write (list 1 2))
(1 2)
> (list 1 2)
(1 2)
```

Comment: Thanks! The write style did the trick. I was using #lang planet neil/sicp. But now with the write style language shows as SICP PLaneT 1.16 custom and says 'read: #lang not enabled in the current context', I had to comment out the #land line to make it work.

Comment: Cool.  I'll follow up with Neil later to see if his package's defaults can be changed so that it's **write** by default.

Comment: How do you configure the output style if you're running from a terminal rather than DrRacket? (I'm running Racket via geiser-mode in Emacs).

Comment: @crowding See: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._global-port-print-handler%29%29.  For example, you can configure the default print handler to not use expression-style printing by doing *(print-as-expression #f)*.

Comment: @dyoo May I know what the outcome of your following up with Neil is?