# Change output printing style from Racket REPL

Tags: emacs, racket, read-eval-print-loop, sicp

I'm doing problems from SICP, using the `#lang planet/neil` directive in Racket. I'd prefer to write my code in Emacs, and I'm using Geiser-mode to run a Racket REPL through Emacs.

The way racket prints results tends to use a lot of `mcons` which makes the results hard to read.

```
racket@chap2.4.rkt> (list 1 2 3 4)
(mcons 1 (mcons 2 (mcons 3 (mcons 4 '()))))
```

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347294/mcons-in-dr-racket), the output style can be changed inside DrRacket by selecting the "write" output style in the Choose Language dialog box. However this requires the DrRacket GUI; is there a way to change this setting for the Racket REPL?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Background: Unlike SICP style Scheme, Racket `list`s are immutable. To get mutable lists, in Racket you use `mlist`. What `#lang planet/neil/SICP` does (I'm guesing) is `(require mpair)` and then rename `mlist` to `list`.  So when you write `list` in that `#lang`, you're actually using `mlist`.

Anyway, `mlist`s print differently, by default. But you can change two parameters.

## [print-as-expression](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._print-as-expression%29%29)

```
(print-as-expression #f)
```

Now it will print as

```
{1 2 3 4}
```

The curly braces instead of parentheses indicate that it's a mutable list. To tweak *that*, set another parameter:

## [print-mpair-curly-braces](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._print-mpair-curly-braces%29%29)

```
(print-mpair-curly-braces #f)
```

And now it should print as:

```
(1 2 3 4)
```

---

To have the plain Racket REPL always do this, I think you could put these two expressions in your [Racket init file](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html?#%28idx._%28gentag._288._%28lib._scribblings%2Freference%2Freference..scrbl%29%29%29), e.g. `~/.racketrc` on OSX and Linux. Although I'm not sure if the REPL provided by Geiser read the init file, if you eval those expressions once they should persist for a Geiser REPL session, so you could put them in some `.rkt` file and visit it once.

Comment: Thanks! One thing to add, these commands aren't accessible when the REPL is inside SICP, but I can type `,enter #f` or press `C-c C-m` in geiser to get back to top level.

Comment: Ah, OK, so `#lang SICP` doesn't provide them. I think you can use `(require (only-in racket/base print-as-expression print-mpair-curly-braces))` to make them available.

Comment: As a sidenote, you can, rather easily, make Geiser read the `~/.racketrc` file by placing the following in your `geiser-racket-init-file` (which is located at `~/.racket-geiser` by default): `(load (find-system-path 'init-file))`